# How do keep auto-correct from making one particular change

Tags: macos, autocorrect

An email address I frequently type into web forms is `srs@...`. Yesterday auto-correct started changing the `srs` to `sis` as soon as I typed `@`. While keeping the rest of auto-correct working I would really like it to leave `srs` alone.

In my searching for an answer I found *[Is it possible (and how do I do it) to change what word Auto-Correct chooses when I make a typo?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/114424/2708)* But I'm not making a typo.

I found a variety of answers for both OS X and iOS, but none seemed to the point. The worst was decrypting a substitution file maintained by Safari to edit?!

Answer (score 2):

Add a text replacement for `srs` to `srs`. This appears to preempt autocomplete from changing it. The technique is the similar to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114657/2708) for how to choose the correction to a typo.

To suppress a specific auto-correction:

1. Open *System Preferences*
2. Open *Keyboard*
3. Choose the *Text* tab.
4. Click the *+* below the replacement list.
5. Add the same word to the *Replace* and *With* columns
6. Close System Preferences.